# Samsung Ml-1600 printer unrecognized

Tags: printing, samsung

**EDIT**: Im using Ubuntu 15.04 (MATE), but from what I can remember, it didnt work on 14.10 (Unity) either!

Hi everybody, as much as I dont like asking questions, Im forced to do so...
Ive been browsing this site and googling the internet like forever! Tried to acces cups via [browser](http://localhost:631/) and add printer that way, but of course nothing has happened!

System just wont see my printer. I Installed [Unified linux drivers](http://bchemnet.com/suldr/suld.html), tried to copy ppd file to/etc/cups/ppd, to no avail. Ive been messing with my system so much, that Im afraid reinstallation might be awaiting me :D (when I changed smth, I have always returned it to orignal form,so I hope everything is OK)

Here are few leads:

```
$ lsusb | grep Samsung
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04e8:3301 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 

$ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/002
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root lp 189, 1 kvě  4 00:20 /dev/bus/usb/001/002

$ grep usb /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id", IMPORT{builtin}="hwdb --subsystem=usb"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:0701??:*", GROUP="lp"
KERNEL=="legousbtower*", MODE="0666"

lsmod | grep usblp
usblp                  20480  0 

$ sudo grep SystemGroup /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
(no output)

$ sudo  /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb
DEBUG: Loading USB quirks from "/usr/share/cups/usb".
DEBUG: Loaded 114 quirks.
DEBUG: list_devices
DEBUG: libusb_get_device_list=6
DEBUG: Failed to open device, code: -1
```

**Any help will greatly appreciated!**

**EDIT**

I followed steps from link you have provided, instead of using their installer.... I installed these packages: `suld-driver-3.00.90` (tried 4.x.x before but to no avail either), `suld-configurator-2-qt4` .... here is how it looks [image: configurator]. When I click "add printer" in samsung utility nothing happens... next window is system printer utility and what I get, when I click "add printer"

This is what CUPS looks like in browser [image: CUPS]

At first I mistook my printer for Hp (no idea why), but Ive removed
 HPLIP properly!

**EDIT2**: Tried different cable and removing CUPS PDF - problem persists
**EDIT3**: install CUPS PDF again

**EDIT4**:I have no idea how, but after reboot... following steps from EDIT2 and 3, my printer somehow appeared in selection!!!

Comment: I have an ML-1675 printer and it works when using the http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ Samsung printer driver repository. No need to fiddle with udev settings, it will work because of proper packaging then. I only needed to add the printer manually in system settings, by selecting the right printer model (two entries exist, the plain Ubuntu one and those installed from the SULDR packages). Just to be clear; is your question 15.04 specific or not? Did it work with an older Ubuntu release? Please [edit] your question to include more of those details.

Comment: You did not reboot after the suldr package installation? You are urged to reboot during installation with a dpkg postinstall script warning you. This is due to permissions being set on your local user account and also for udev some rules required for CUPS being able to access the device. They only become active after restarting udev and logging out and logging back in. Effectively, rebooting is the easy advice though. So, it works now? I'm happy to provide this as an answer here.

Comment: Trust me I have rebooted after everything .... this is one thing Im used to from times, when I was using Windows.